# retain xml fragment across orientation changes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, orientation-changes

I am using the `<fragment>` tag to add a Fragment to an Activity. The fragment contains a TextureView that is playing a video. How do I keep the video playing on orientation changes?

FYI: My fragment has other stuff in it such as Service and Broadcast receiver, so I am looking for a solid engineering solution. For instance, if I use

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

It may cause my service to leak on orientation change.

I am reading the fragments document and am looking at answers here as well. But fragments are such complicated features that I need a bit extra help.

Comment: **Note:** I don't want to lock the orientation of the parent activity. I need the orientation to change as per usual. I fact, I need the VidoeFragment to become "fullscreen" in landscape while occupying a small portion of the window in portrait mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tied this:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

or for Android 3.2 (API level 13) and newer:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Answer (score 1):

In your activity manifest

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

then override onConfigurationChanged

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: ????? what does this do? I don't want to lock the orientation of the parent activity. I need the orientation to change as per usual. I fact, I need the VidoeFragment to become "fullscreen" in landscape while occupying a small portion of the window in portrait mode. Thanks for responding, but there isn't enough detail in your answer.

Comment: Blocks the orientation on the activity

Comment: Sorry, dude. The portrait portion got me there. +1. Thanks. I came to accept yours with correction but saw someone with the actual correct answer that I used.